# Blank Pages in CF10 for .CFM (uppercase only) pages

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7, coldfusion-10

We have multiple servers with IIS7 and ColdFusion.  Some are CF9, some are CF10.  Coldfusion pages ending in ".cfm" (lowercase) render correctly on both.  However, if you type in ".CFM" (uppercase) as the browser url, the Coldfusion 10 servers return a blank white page. (page source is empty also)   The Coldfusion 9 server renders the page normally. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Just ran a page with CF 9.01 on IIS 7 and did not see it happen. Are you trying to show the default document?

Comment: Because CF10 is on Tomcat, it's more case-sensitive with these things than JRun was. That's the issue. You need to tweak one of your Tomcat config files... which I will need to be vague about as I don't have CF10 in front of me for another 4h or so. However it's a) expected; b) easily fixed; c) will be documented on blogs as people have been hit by this before. So do a google, and if you can't find it (or no-one else comes back in the mean time), I'll post an actual answer this evening when I get home (UK time).

Comment: The bug refeenced below -  https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3199283 - details the work around (for all-caps file extensions). That was what I was meaning above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coldfusion 10 is supposed to be case sensitive when it comes to file names.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4524330

The CF10 case-sensitivity bugs ([#3199281](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3199281) & [#3199283](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3199283))

Comment: would you said that case-sensitivity is a bug? Not with tomcat or JAVA I don't think it should be treated as a bug personally.

Comment: @GlynJackson: it's a regression. Previously versions of CF weren't case-sensitive in this way, CF10 now is. This will cause regression errors (as you have seen).

Answer (score 4):

ColdFusion 10’s built-in Tomcat web server handles case sensitivity different than the old JRun built-in web server. Basically, it follows the RFC and is case sensitive.

See this bug report in the CF 10 bugbase: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3199283

Additional detail can be found here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k37HvumHZQTThJQRk99rIttc5k8ykm2BBVmJ4XZIjpY/edit